# ConTeXt does not load png file given by lua code

Tags: luatex, context, expansion

This is my code:

```
\defineexpandable[1]\background{
  \directlua{
    local cases = {
      "noise-blue.png",
      "noise-yellow.png",
      "noise-red.png",
      "noise-green.png"
    }

    tex.sprint(cases[#1])
  }
}

\starttext
  \background{1}                             % (1)
  \externalfigure[noise-blue.png][width=4cm] % (2)
  \externalfigure[\background{1}][width=4cm] % (3)
\stoptext
```

`(1)` gives me `noise-blue.png` in the output.
`(2)` correctly renders the image `noise-blue.png`.
`(3)` gives a gray box with

```
name: noise-blue.png
file: noise-blue.png
state: unknown
```

Why doesn't it render the image?

Comment: The `\background` command already exists in ConTeXt, use `\Background` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You add spaces in the output of your command at the begin and end of the definition.

```
\defineexpandable[1]\Background{
  \directlua{
    local cases = {
      "noise-blue.png",
      "noise-yellow.png",
      "noise-red.png",
      "noise-green.png"
    }
    tex.sprint(cases[#1])
  }
}

\starttext
“\Background{1}”
\stoptext
```

[image]

To get rid of the spaces you have to add a comment sign after the braces.

```
\defineexpandable[1]\Background{%
  \directlua{
    local cases = {
      "noise-blue.png",
      "noise-yellow.png",
      "noise-red.png",
      "noise-green.png"
    }
    tex.sprint(cases[#1])
  }%
}

\starttext
“\Background{1}”
\stoptext
```

[image]

You can also use the `texdefinition` environment to create the command which doesn’t convert the end of a line into a space.

```
\starttexdefinition Background #1
  \startlua
    local cases = {
        "noise-blue.png",
        "noise-yellow.png",
        "noise-red.png",
        "noise-green.png"
    }
    context(cases[#1])
  \stoplua
\stoptexdefinition
```

### Alternative solution

A different way to create a index for your images is the `\setvariables` which you can use to assign a key to each image. The graphics can than be accessed with the `\getvariable` command.

```
\setvariables
  [background]
  [1={noise-blue.png},
   2={noise-yellow.png},
   3={noise-red.png},
   4={noise-green.png}]

\starttext
“\getvariable{background}{1}”
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to Wolfgang's answer and as alternative to your Lua solution, you might want to consider using [`\useexternalfigure`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useexternalfigure) which allows you to name figures.

```
\useexternalfigure[background:1][noise-blue.png]
\useexternalfigure[background:2][noise-yellow.png]
\useexternalfigure[background:3][noise-red.png]
\useexternalfigure[background:4][noise-green.png]

\starttext
  \externalfigure[background:1][width=4cm]
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I'll keep Wolfgang's answer accepted since it solves the question but I'll consider using this code instead.